# Can you build a One Way function from a Collision Resistant Function Family?

Tags: collision-resistance, one-way-function

The assumption is you have a Collision Resistant function(CRF) Family F. How do you use F to build a One Way function (OWF).

One Idea I have is to use 2 functions from the CRF Family. Both these functions have n input and n/2 output. You as a user inputs n bits ({0,1}^n) and get an output of n, by using 2 of these functions that output n/2 and concatenate them together to get n output.

This would work in creating a one-way function? or is the idea of a one-way function is that it needs to be able to be inverted, but that it is computationally difficult to do so, while a CRF you can not invert to the original answer?

Comment: Doesn't collision resistance directly imply one-wayness?

Comment: @fkraiem Yes in fact it does I was confusing myself. I simply needed a proof to show this. And I figured something out so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So in fact, you can build a One-way function from a Collision Resistant Function.

Using a function family of CR functions F, we can create a one way function that works as follows:

pick function F from CRF family, F = ${f_k}$
$g =\ one\ way\ function$
$x_1\ and\ x_2$ picked from random

$g(x_1, x_2) = f_{x_1}(x_2),\ x_1$

The reason this works is because in order to break this one way function you would have to break the fact that $f_{x_1}$ is collision resistant.

**Proof:**

So let us assume there is an adversary A
that can invert CR function $f_{x_1}(x)\rightarrow y$.

$A(y) \rightarrow x$
What A returns is a pre-image of x so it can be the original x or a collision.
So now lets assume there exists an A' that can use A to break our one way function.
The way he will do so is by first allowing the random inputs of $x_1\ and\ x_2$.
$g(x_1, x_2)= f_{x_1}(x_2),\ x_1 \rightarrow y$

Now A' uses $A(y)\rightarrow x$ The output x is either = $x_1$ or a collision. With this A' has now successfully broken my scheme. But because we know that an adversary A that can find a collision/invert a collision resistant function does not exist in polynomial time we know our scheme is safe and one way because if one can not find a collision in polynomial time then one can not break the one wayness of my function in polynomial time.

Comment: The logic in this answer is wrong. You use an adversary for the CRF to get an adversary for the one-way function - but that just shows that *if it is a one-way function, then $f_k$ was collision resistant*. You want / need to show the other direction.

Comment: And in fact, according to [this reference](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/oneway.html) your direction is not sufficient.

Comment: Truncate the output like sha-3?